# Unable to manipulate DOM of external page elements loaded by AJAX load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

I have following HTMl in index.php

```
<div id="internal" class="internal-class"></div>
<a href="external.php #external-element" class="button">Load</a>
```

And CSS like this

```
    #internal {

        padding: 50px;
        background: green;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #external-element {

        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

And I have one external php page external.php like this

```
<div id="external-element" class="external-class"></div>
```

I have used the following script in index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $('a').click(function(event){

            $attrib = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#internal').load($attrib,function(){

                alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
                alert($('.external-element').attr('class'));

            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

In the above code the jQuery script successfully loads the #external-element from external.php in the div #internal. And after loading I wanted to alert classes of both #internal as well as #external-element.

```
$('#internal').load($attrib,function(){

                alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
                alert($('.external-element').attr('class'));

});
```

above code successfully alerts the name of class of #internal & #external-element.
but when I write

```
            $('#internal').load($attrib);
            alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
            alert($('#external-element').attr('class'));
```

then above code is not alerting the class of #external-element. It is saying undefined.

I think , it is unable to manipulate DOM of external.php after AJAX load(). Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: `#` use for id and `.` for class in css, jquery.

Comment: @Prashant - He know well. he just made silly mistake

Comment: @sudharsan: i dont think so because his writing style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`external-element` is not a class. it is a id.

Put `'#'` before it instead of `'.'`

```
alert($('#external-element').attr('class'));
```

Comment: @GauravDeshpande: welcome to SO... do upvote and accept helped answer.